# Js function run 2 time on phonegap build

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a trouble with a phonegap build, a function run two time (on my mobile with the phonegap build), differently when i execute the script on firefox.

Thats a part of my code :

```
$(".blackcase").click(function(e)
{
    if (elemIsEmpty($(this)) && isSelected("black"))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (isSelected("white"))
    {
        //swap white to black
        alert("swap b to w");
        if ($(this).html() == valueoffirst.html())
        {
            $(valueoffirst.html(""));
            alert("swap   b to w1");
        }
        else
        {
            swapValuesFromTo($("#" + selectedCase.id), $(this));
            alert("swap b to w 2");
        }
        clearSelectedCase();
        removeSelectionWithRed();
        return;
    }
    if (isSelected("black"))
    {
        alert("swap b to b");
        $("#" + selectedCase.id).removeClass('red');
        if ($(this).html() == valueoffirst.html() && $(this).attr('id') != valueoffirst.attr('id'))
        {
            $(valueoffirst.html(""));
            alert("swap   b to b1");
        }
        else
        {
            swapValuesFromTo($("#" + selectedCase.id), $(this));
            alert("swap b to b 2");
        }
        clearSelectedCase();
        removeSelectionWithRed();
        return;
    }
    //alert("black is selected");
    selectWithRed($(this));
    updateSelectedCase("black", $(this).attr("id"), $(this).html());
    valueoffirst = $(this);
});

function removeSelectionWithRed()
{
    $('div').removeClass('red');
}

function selectWithRed(element)
{
    removeSelectionWithRed();
    element.addClass('red');
}

function updateSelectedCase(color, id)
{
    selectedCase.color = color;
    selectedCase.id = id;
}

function moveValueFromTo(elemFrom, elemTo)
{
    elemTo.html(elemFrom.html());
    setValueToElem("", elemFrom);
}

function setValueToElem(value, elem)
{
    elem.html(value);
}

function swapValuesFromTo(elemFrom, elemTo)
{
    var fromValue = elemFrom.html();
    var toValue = elemTo.html();
    setValueToElem(fromValue, elemTo);
    setValueToElem(toValue, elemFrom);
}

function isSelected(color)
{
    return selectedCase.color == color;
}

function clearSelectedCase()
{
    selectedCase.color = "";
    selectedCase.id = "";
}

function elemIsEmpty(elem)
{
    return elem.html().length == 0;
}
```

When i run my code on firefox, if i click on black case then on another blackcase, it's swapping the values and i have two alerts :

swap b to b

Swap b to b2

All is ok, but on my mobile with my phongap build test, if i click on blackcase then another blackcase the values don't swap and i have 4 alerts :

swap b to b

Swap b to b2

swap b to b

Swap b to b2

So i think values swap but reswap so values are sames of the starting values (like nothing changing).

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Sounds like something is adding your click handler more than once. where is `$(".blackcase").click(function(){})` called from

Comment: Thanks, yes but i don't undertand why it's ok on firefox, there is a js specification for phonegap or another think like this  ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably it fired the touch event as well while run in mobile platform. Try to register touch event to test if it does fired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i should to try to replace click event by touch ?

Comment: If you are develop for mobile platform, click should be replace with touch event.